# Get the reloaded URL in Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

Is it possible to get the reloaded url in **Java**?

I need to retrieve the token append to the url after loading below HTML page.

Initially the URL will be

`http://localhost:8080/validate.html?invisible=true`

After the successful `google-recaptcha` it will be

`http://localhost:8080/validate.html?token=xyz`

I need to retrieve the token value in Java.

I have tried with the below piece of code but the `location` var is returning `null`.

Any solutions?

```java
final String htmlUrl = "http://localhost:8080/validate.html?invisible=true";
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL( htmlUrl ).openConnection());
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( true );

con.connect();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println( responseCode );
String location = con.getHeaderField( "Location" );
System.out.println( location );
```

```html
<html>
  <script> function reCaptchaCallback(token){ window.location = '?token=' + token; } </script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/**.js?render=123"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/**.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>
  <script>
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    if (!url.searchParams.get('token')) {
      if (url.searchParams.get('visible') != 'true') {
        grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('123', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
            reCaptchaCallback(token);
          });
        });        
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
      if (url.searchParams.get('visible') == 'true') {
        grecaptcha.enterprise.render('recaptcha', { 'sitekey' : '123', 'callback': 'reCaptchaCallback' });        
      }
    };
  </script>

  <body style= "display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <div id="recaptcha"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible (at least with `HttpURLConnection`)

First problem is that Location header is set by a web server to redirect user.
You are altering the location clientside by changing `window.location` (which is not related to `Location` header sent when loading the site.

Second problem is that `HttpURLConnection` only does one request that loads `validate.html`. Creating a connection doesn't work like opening a website with your browser. Your browser does much more (it parses the HTML, loads images, scripts and other files, executes javascript / wasm files and renders your html/css after connecting and getting contents of your `validate.html`).

You could do something like this by using a headless browser such as `chromium`. For that you will need to use a library like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/)